# Do those who practice family purity get cervical cancer less?

Tags: science, niddah, choleh-sick

Is there a good study which shows that those who practice family purity get cervical cancer far less? Not just comparing Orthodox women to other groups, but amongst Jews? And is conclusive.

Comment: "And is conclusive"? I think *no* scientific study claims to be 100% conclusive. Or do you want to specify a [significance level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significance_level#Use_in_practice)? Anyway, welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.

Comment: If you are just looking for scientific studies consider asking on [Skeptics.SE] if you don't get anything here.

Comment: @DoubleAA, they insist on questions that seek proof/debunking of a notable claim. This question would have to include info indicating that the claim ChaimZalmon's asking about is, in fact, notable. (Just FYI, C.Z.)

Comment: Try this search on PubMed http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%22Uterine%20Cervical%20Neoplasms%22%5BMAJR%5D%20%22Jews%22%5BMAJR%5D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about medical research not about Judaism.

Answer (score 10):

[This article from Dr J Menczer](http://www.cirp.org/library/disease/cancer/menczer1/) indicates that although there is a significantly lower incidence of cervical cancer amongst Jews it is not due to family purity laws, as even Jews who do not observe these laws have a lower incidence of cervical cancer.

Comment: ...citing an earlier study by Stewart et al. to that effect, actually. +1, though.